# How do you add an exclusion to this formula?

Tags: excel

Here is my formula:

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(0,COUNTIF(C$13:C13,'Raw Data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000&"" ),0)),"",INDEX(IF(ISBLANK(
 'Raw Data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000),"",'Raw Data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$13:C13,'Raw Data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000&""),0)))

This is an array formula which requires that you hit control + shift + enter.

The formula takes a list and removes all duplicate values from that list.  But I need to modify this formula slightly and that's where I'm running into the issue.  I do NOT want it to include any cells that have the words "Select".

In my range, I have certain cells that say "Select."  But I do not want these cells included as part of the output.  This is a tough one and a little beyond me.

$Q$14:$Q$1000 is the range.
C13 is the first value in the output list and is equal to Q14.

Comment: For clarification, are you just wanting to alter the IF statement so if a cell is blank or contains "Select", it returns the ""?

Comment: I DO need to alter the IF statement.  I want "Select" to not appear in my output.  So in the output, rather than that cell saying "Select", it will just go to the next value as it weeds out duplicates.  Basically, my range is composed of pull-down menus and one of the choices in each menu is "Select."  But there are a lot of rows that are not yet populated so "Select" is still present in the range for a lot of cells.  And it's causing difficulties in summarizing my data.  So as I drag down my output to weed out the duplicates, I do not want "Select" to appear.

Comment: Are you trying to get a single result or is this a helper column?

Comment: No....this is not a helper column.  As you pull this formula down, it gives each unique value in the list until there are no more.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Excel are you using? If `Excel 2007` or later you can use this version which utilises `IFERROR` function

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Raw data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000&"",MATCH(1,('Raw data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000<>"")*('Raw data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000<>"Select")*(COUNTIF(C$13:C13,'Raw data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000)=0),0)),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That won't show any blanks (except after all non-blanks are shown), do you want to show a blank if there is one?

Assuming it's possible for the first cell (Q14) to be "Select" you might also need to change C14 to the following:

`=INDEX('Raw data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000,MATCH(TRUE,'Raw data'!$Q$14:$Q$1000<>"Select",0))`

also "array entered"

Comment: That first formula seems to work really well.  Thank you.  That's a big help!